# wxWidgets sample files mediaplayer ans splash don't compile

Tags: c++, makefile, g++, gstreamer, wxwidgets

I downloaded and built the **wxWidgets library** on *Ubuntu 21.04* using the following flags:

```
--enable-monolithic
--disable-shared
--enable-cxx11
--enable-stl
--enable-std_containers_compat
--enable-std_iostreams
--enable-std_string
--enable-std_string_conv_in_wxstring
--disable-unsafe_conv_in_wxstring
--enable-utf8
--enable-profile
--disable-vararg_macros
--enable-universal_binary
--enable-intl
--enable-config
--enable-protocols
--enable-ftp
--enable-http
--enable-fileproto
--enable-sockets
--enable-ipv6
--enable-dataobj
--enable-webrequest
--enable-ipc
--enable-baseevtloop
--enable-epollloop
--enable-selectloop
--enable-any
--enable-arcstream
--enable-base64
--enable-backtrace
--enable-catch_segvs
--enable-cmdline
--enable-datetime
--enable-debugreport
--enable-dialupman
--enable-dynlib
--enable-dynamicloader
--enable-exceptions
--enable-ffile
--enable-file
--enable-filehistory
--enable-filesystem
--enable-fontenum
--enable-fontmap
--enable-fs_archive
--enable-fs_inet
--enable-fsvolume
--enable-fswatcher
--enable-geometry
--enable-log
--enable-longlong
--enable-mimetype
--enable-printfposparam
--enable-secretstore
--enable-snglinst
--enable-sound
--enable-stdpaths
--enable-stopwatch
--enable-streams
--enable-sysoptions
--enable-tarstream
--enable-textbuf
--enable-textfile
--enable-timer
--enable-variant
--enable-zipstream
--enable-url
--enable-protocol
--enable-protocol-http
--enable-protocol-ftp
--enable-protocol-file
--enable-threads
--enable-docview
--enable-help
--enable-html
--enable-htmlhelp
--enable-xrc
--enable-aui
--enable-propgrid
--enable-ribbon
--enable-stc
--enable-constraints
--enable-loggui
--enable-logwin
--enable-logdialog
--enable-mdi
--enable-mdidoc
--enable-mediactrl
--enable-richtext
--enable-postscript
--enable-printarch
--enable-svg
--enable-webview
--enable-graphics_ctx
--enable-clipboard
--enable-dnd
--enable-markup
--enable-accel
--enable-actindicator
--enable-addremovectrl
--enable-animatectrl
--enable-bannerwindow
--enable-artstd
--enable-arttango
--enable-bmpbutton
--enable-bmpcombobox
--enable-button
--enable-calendar
--enable-caret
--enable-checkbox
--enable-checklst
--enable-choice
--enable-choicebook
--enable-collpane
--enable-colourpicker
--enable-combobox
--enable-comboctrl
--enable-commandlinkbutton
--enable-dataviewctrl
--enable-datepick
--enable-detect_sm
--enable-dirpicker
--enable-display
--enable-editablebox
--enable-filectrl
--enable-filepicker
--enable-fontpicker
--enable-gauge
--enable-grid
--enable-headerctrl
--enable-hyperlink
--enable-imaglist
--enable-infobar
--enable-listbook
--enable-listbox
--enable-listctrl
--enable-notebook
--enable-notifmsg
--enable-odcombobox
--enable-popupwin
--enable-prefseditor
--enable-privatefonts
--enable-radiobox
--enable-radiobtn
--enable-richmsgdlg
--enable-richtooltip
--enable-rearrangectrl
--enable-sash
--enable-scrollbar
--enable-searchctrl
--enable-slider
--enable-spinbtn
--enable-spinctrl
--enable-splitter
--enable-statbmp
--enable-statbox
--enable-statline
--enable-stattext
--enable-statusbar
--enable-taskbaricon
--enable-tbarnative
--enable-textctrl
--enable-timepick
--enable-tipwindow
--enable-togglebtn
--enable-toolbar
--enable-toolbook
--enable-treebook
--enable-treectrl
--enable-treelist
--enable-commondlg
--enable-aboutdlg
--enable-choicedlg
--enable-coldlg
--enable-creddlg
--enable-filedlg
--enable-finddlg
--enable-fontdlg
--enable-dirdlg
--enable-msgdlg
--enable-numberdlg
--enable-splash
--enable-textdlg
--enable-tipdlg
--enable-progressdlg
--enable-wizarddlg
--enable-menus
--enable-menubar
--enable-miniframe
--enable-tooltips
--enable-splines
--enable-mousewheel
--enable-validators
--enable-busyinfo
--enable-hotkey
--enable-joystick
--enable-metafile
--enable-dragimage
--enable-dctransform
--enable-webviewwebkit
--enable-palette
--enable-image
--enable-gif
--enable-pcx
--enable-tga
--enable-iff
--enable-pnm
--enable-xpm
--enable-ico_cur
--enable-autoidman
```

I used all these flags because I mainly want to play around with the library and having a static, monolithic library with all the features enabled suits that purpose. At first I faced some issues at configuration with ***GStreamer*** which wasn't installed but after I installed it the library compiled just fine. For the sake of completeness, these are the exact steps I followed:

```
#Current dir -> ~/Programs/C++/wxWidgets-3.1.5
mkdir build-gtk
cd build-gtk
../configure #all the above flags
make
sudo checkinstall
```

and finally I installed the library through the generated `.deb` file.

I then proceeded to build the sample files with the provided `make` files. All but two compiled, **mediaplayer** and **splash** directories. Again, the exact procedure I followed was:

```
cd samples
make
```

The error I got for ***mediaplayer*** is:

```
/usr/bin/ld: ~/Programs/C++/wxWidgets-3.1.5/build-gtk/lib/libwx_gtk3u-3.1.a(monolib_unix_mediactrl.o): in function `draw':
mediactrl.cpp:(.text+0x195): undefined reference to `gst_video_overlay_expose'
/usr/bin/ld: ~/Programs/C++/wxWidgets-3.1.5/build-gtk/lib/libwx_gtk3u-3.1.a(monolib_unix_mediactrl.o): in function `wxGStreamerMediaBackend::SetPosition(wxLongLongNative)':
mediactrl.cpp:(.text+0x200): undefined reference to `gst_element_seek'
/usr/bin/ld: ~/Programs/C++/wxWidgets-3.1.5/build-gtk/lib/libwx_gtk3u-3.1.a(monolib_unix_mediactrl.o): in function `wxGStreamerMediaBackend::GetDuration()':
mediactrl.cpp:(.text+0x24f): undefined reference to `gst_element_query_duration'
/usr/bin/ld: ~/Programs/C++/wxWidgets-3.1.5/build-gtk/lib/libwx_gtk3u-3.1.a(monolib_unix_mediactrl.o): in function `wxGStreamerMediaBackend::GetDownloadTotal()':
mediactrl.cpp:(.text+0x2cf): undefined reference to `gst_element_query_duration'
/usr/bin/ld: ~/Programs/C++/wxWidgets-3.1.5/build-gtk/lib/libwx_gtk3u-3.1.a(monolib_unix_mediactrl.o): in function `wxGStreamerMediaBackend::GetPosition()':
mediactrl.cpp:(.text+0x545): undefined reference to `gst_element_query_position'
/usr/bin/ld: ~/Programs/C++/wxWidgets-3.1.5/build-gtk/lib/libwx_gtk3u-3.1.a(monolib_unix_mediactrl.o): in function `gtk_window_realize_callback':
mediactrl.cpp:(.text+0x615): undefined reference to `gst_video_overlay_set_window_handle'
/usr/bin/ld: ~/Programs/C++/wxWidgets-3.1.5/build-gtk/lib/libwx_gtk3u-3.1.a(monolib_unix_mediactrl.o): in function `wxGStreamerMediaBackend::~wxGStreamerMediaBackend()':
mediactrl.cpp:(.text+0x6e6): undefined reference to `gst_object_get_type'
/usr/bin/ld: mediactrl.cpp:(.text+0x75a): undefined reference to `gst_element_set_state'
/usr/bin/ld: mediactrl.cpp:(.text+0x75f): undefined reference to `gst_object_get_type'
/usr/bin/ld: mediactrl.cpp:(.text+0x773): undefined reference to `gst_object_unref'
/usr/bin/ld: ~/Programs/C++/wxWidgets-3.1.5/build-gtk/lib/libwx_gtk3u-3.1.a(monolib_unix_mediactrl.o): in function `wxGStreamerMediaBackend::SetupXOverlay()':
mediactrl.cpp:(.text+0x918): undefined reference to `gst_video_overlay_set_window_handle'
/usr/bin/ld: ~/Programs/C++/wxWidgets-3.1.5/build-gtk/lib/libwx_gtk3u-3.1.a(monolib_unix_mediactrl.o): in function `wxGStreamerMediaBackend::TryAudioSink(_GstElement*)':
mediactrl.cpp:(.text+0xac8): undefined reference to `gst_element_get_type'
/usr/bin/ld: ~/Programs/C++/wxWidgets-3.1.5/build-gtk/lib/libwx_gtk3u-3.1.a(monolib_unix_mediactrl.o): in function `wxGStreamerMediaBackend::TryVideoSink(_GstElement*)':
mediactrl.cpp:(.text+0xb5e): undefined reference to `gst_bin_get_type'
/usr/bin/ld: mediactrl.cpp:(.text+0xb89): undefined reference to `gst_video_overlay_get_type'
/usr/bin/ld: mediactrl.cpp:(.text+0xbaf): undefined reference to `gst_bin_get_type'
/usr/bin/ld: mediactrl.cpp:(.text+0xbd1): undefined reference to `gst_video_overlay_get_type'
/usr/bin/ld: mediactrl.cpp:(.text+0xbd9): undefined reference to `gst_bin_get_type'
/usr/bin/ld: mediactrl.cpp:(.text+0xbef): undefined reference to `gst_bin_get_by_interface'
/usr/bin/ld: mediactrl.cpp:(.text+0xbfb): undefined reference to `gst_video_overlay_get_type'
/usr/bin/ld: mediactrl.cpp:(.text+0xc2a): undefined reference to `gst_element_set_state'
/usr/bin/ld: mediactrl.cpp:(.text+0xc50): undefined reference to `gst_video_overlay_get_type'
/usr/bin/ld: mediactrl.cpp:(.text+0xc61): undefined reference to `gst_video_overlay_get_type'
/usr/bin/ld: ~/Programs/C++/wxWidgets-3.1.5/build-gtk/lib/libwx_gtk3u-3.1.a(monolib_unix_mediactrl.o): in function `wxGStreamerMediaBackend::CreateControl(wxControl*, wxWindow*, int, wxPoint const&, wxSize const&, long, wxValidator const&, wxString const&)':
mediactrl.cpp:(.text+0x100c): undefined reference to `gst_init_check'
/usr/bin/ld: mediactrl.cpp:(.text+0x122a): undefined reference to `gst_element_factory_make'
/usr/bin/ld: mediactrl.cpp:(.text+0x1236): undefined reference to `gst_element_get_type'
/usr/bin/ld: mediactrl.cpp:(.text+0x190c): undefined reference to `gst_element_get_bus'
/usr/bin/ld: mediactrl.cpp:(.text+0x191e): undefined reference to `gst_bus_add_watch'
/usr/bin/ld: mediactrl.cpp:(.text+0x1927): undefined reference to `gst_element_get_bus'
/usr/bin/ld: mediactrl.cpp:(.text+0x193b): undefined reference to `gst_bus_set_sync_handler'
/usr/bin/ld: mediactrl.cpp:(.text+0x194e): undefined reference to `gst_element_factory_make'
/usr/bin/ld: mediactrl.cpp:(.text+0x1977): undefined reference to `gst_element_factory_make'
/usr/bin/ld: mediactrl.cpp:(.text+0x19a0): undefined reference to `gst_element_factory_make'
/usr/bin/ld: mediactrl.cpp:(.text+0x1b4f): undefined reference to `gst_element_factory_make'
/usr/bin/ld: mediactrl.cpp:(.text+0x1b7f): undefined reference to `gst_element_factory_make'
/usr/bin/ld: ~/Programs/C++/wxWidgets-3.1.5/build-gtk/lib/libwx_gtk3u-3.1.a(monolib_unix_mediactrl.o):mediactrl.cpp:(.text+0x1ba8): more undefined references to `gst_element_factory_make' follow
/usr/bin/ld: ~/Programs/C++/wxWidgets-3.1.5/build-gtk/lib/libwx_gtk3u-3.1.a(monolib_unix_mediactrl.o): in function `wxGStreamerMediaBackend::CreateControl(wxControl*, wxWindow*, int, wxPoint const&, wxSize const&, long, wxValidator const&, wxString const&)':
mediactrl.cpp:(.text+0x1d2b): undefined reference to `gst_element_get_static_pad'
/usr/bin/ld: mediactrl.cpp:(.text+0x1d5c): undefined reference to `gst_object_unref'
/usr/bin/ld: ~/Programs/C++/wxWidgets-3.1.5/build-gtk/lib/libwx_gtk3u-3.1.a(monolib_unix_mediactrl.o): in function `wxGStreamerMediaBackend::Play()':
mediactrl.cpp:(.text+0x30d1): undefined reference to `gst_element_set_state'
/usr/bin/ld: ~/Programs/C++/wxWidgets-3.1.5/build-gtk/lib/libwx_gtk3u-3.1.a(monolib_unix_mediactrl.o): in function `wxGStreamerMediaBackend::Pause()':
mediactrl.cpp:(.text+0x312c): undefined reference to `gst_element_set_state'
/usr/bin/ld: ~/Programs/C++/wxWidgets-3.1.5/build-gtk/lib/libwx_gtk3u-3.1.a(monolib_unix_mediactrl.o): in function `wxGStreamerMediaBackend::QueryVideoSizeFromPad(_GstPad*)':
mediactrl.cpp:(.text+0x3f44): undefined reference to `gst_pad_get_current_caps'
/usr/bin/ld: mediactrl.cpp:(.text+0x3f5a): undefined reference to `gst_caps_get_structure'
/usr/bin/ld: mediactrl.cpp:(.text+0x3f79): undefined reference to `gst_structure_get_int'
/usr/bin/ld: mediactrl.cpp:(.text+0x3f8c): undefined reference to `gst_structure_get_int'
/usr/bin/ld: mediactrl.cpp:(.text+0x3fa2): undefined reference to `gst_structure_get_value'
/usr/bin/ld: mediactrl.cpp:(.text+0x40be): undefined reference to `gst_mini_object_unref'
/usr/bin/ld: ~/Programs/C++/wxWidgets-3.1.5/build-gtk/lib/libwx_gtk3u-3.1.a(monolib_unix_mediactrl.o): in function `gst_bus_async_callback':
mediactrl.cpp:(.text+0x5fe7): undefined reference to `gst_message_parse_state_changed'
/usr/bin/ld: mediactrl.cpp:(.text+0x6014): undefined reference to `gst_message_parse_error'
/usr/bin/ld: ~/Programs/C++/wxWidgets-3.1.5/build-gtk/lib/libwx_gtk3u-3.1.a(monolib_unix_mediactrl.o): in function `gst_bus_sync_callback':
mediactrl.cpp:(.text+0x607a): undefined reference to `gst_is_video_overlay_prepare_window_handle_message'
/usr/bin/ld: ~/Programs/C++/wxWidgets-3.1.5/build-gtk/lib/libwx_gtk3u-3.1.a(monolib_unix_mediactrl.o): in function `wxGStreamerMediaBackend::SyncStateChange(_GstElement*, GstState, long)':
mediactrl.cpp:(.text+0x6497): undefined reference to `gst_element_get_bus'
/usr/bin/ld: mediactrl.cpp:(.text+0x64b0): undefined reference to `gst_bus_have_pending'
/usr/bin/ld: mediactrl.cpp:(.text+0x64f4): undefined reference to `gst_bus_pop'
/usr/bin/ld: mediactrl.cpp:(.text+0x6505): undefined reference to `gst_mini_object_unref'
/usr/bin/ld: mediactrl.cpp:(.text+0x656b): undefined reference to `gst_mini_object_unref'
/usr/bin/ld: mediactrl.cpp:(.text+0x65b9): undefined reference to `gst_message_parse_state_changed'
/usr/bin/ld: mediactrl.cpp:(.text+0x65d3): undefined reference to `gst_mini_object_unref'
/usr/bin/ld: mediactrl.cpp:(.text+0x65fa): undefined reference to `gst_message_parse_error'
/usr/bin/ld: mediactrl.cpp:(.text+0x661c): undefined reference to `gst_mini_object_unref'
/usr/bin/ld: ~/Programs/C++/wxWidgets-3.1.5/build-gtk/lib/libwx_gtk3u-3.1.a(monolib_unix_mediactrl.o): in function `wxGStreamerMediaEventHandler::OnMediaFinish(wxMediaEvent&)':
mediactrl.cpp:(.text+0x69d1): undefined reference to `gst_element_set_state'
/usr/bin/ld: mediactrl.cpp:(.text+0x69fa): undefined reference to `gst_element_set_state'
/usr/bin/ld: ~/Programs/C++/wxWidgets-3.1.5/build-gtk/lib/libwx_gtk3u-3.1.a(monolib_unix_mediactrl.o): in function `wxGStreamerMediaBackend::DoLoad(wxString const&)':
mediactrl.cpp:(.text+0x6ad6): undefined reference to `gst_element_set_state'
/usr/bin/ld: mediactrl.cpp:(.text+0x703a): undefined reference to `gst_element_set_state'
/usr/bin/ld: mediactrl.cpp:(.text+0x7046): undefined reference to `gst_uri_protocol_is_valid'
/usr/bin/ld: mediactrl.cpp:(.text+0x70c0): undefined reference to `gst_uri_is_valid'
/usr/bin/ld: mediactrl.cpp:(.text+0x71f0): undefined reference to `gst_element_set_state'
/usr/bin/ld: ~/Programs/C++/wxWidgets-3.1.5/build-gtk/lib/libwx_gtk3u-3.1.a(monolib_unix_mediactrl.o): in function `wxGStreamerMediaBackend::Stop()':
mediactrl.cpp:(.text+0x7759): undefined reference to `gst_element_set_state'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

`make` tried to compile the the sample running `g++` with the following flags (quoting them in separate lines for readability):

```
g++
-std=gnu++11
-o mediaplayer  mediaplayer_mediaplayer.o   
-L~/Programs/C++/wxWidgets-3.1.5/build-gtk/lib     
-pthread 
-pg  
-lgstvideo-1.0
-lgstbase-1.0
-lgstreamer-1.0
-lgobject-2.0
-lglib-2.0    
-lwx_gtk3u-3.1
-lwxscintilla-3.1      
-lwxregexu-3.1 
-pthread   
-lz
-ldl
-lcurl
-llzma
-lm 
-lexpat
-lgtk-3
-lgdk-3
-lpangocairo-1.0
-lpango-1.0
-lharfbuzz
-latk-1.0
-lcairo-gobject
-lcairo
-lgdk_pixbuf-2.0
-lgio-2.0
-lgobject-2.0
-lgthread-2.0
-pthread
-lglib-2.0
-lX11
-lSM
-lgtk-3
-lgdk-3
-lpangocairo-1.0
-lpango-1.0
-lharfbuzz
-latk-1.0
-lcairo-gobject
-lcairo
-lgdk_pixbuf-2.0
-lgio-2.0
-lgobject-2.0
-lglib-2.0
-lnotify
-lgdk_pixbuf-2.0
-lgio-2.0
-lgobject-2.0
-lglib-2.0
-lXtst
-lpangoft2-1.0
-lpango-1.0
-lgobject-2.0
-lglib-2.0
-lharfbuzz
-lfontconfig
-lfreetype
-lpng
-lz
-ljpeg
-ltiff
-llzma
-ljbig
-lz
-ldl
-lcurl
-llzma
-lm
```

I've been trying two days now to solve this but I can't figured it out. I've tried installing all the possible **GStreamer packages**, copying the GStreamer libraries and **header files** to a bunch of different location, I tried `--reinstall` and other things but at this point I haven't managed to get anywhere. Does anyone know what am I missing here? How can I compile these sample files?

**Edit:**

As @VZ. pointed out I should make more clear that:

1. The `make` files were autogenerated by building wxWidgets library.
2. There was a `makefile` in the `build-gtk/samples` directory which would compile in batch all examples.
3. In each example (e.g. `build-gtk/samples/mediaplayer`) there was a `makefile` generated by a `bakefile` - the first lines are a block comment saying:

```
# =========================================================================
#     This makefile was generated by
#     Bakefile 0.2.12 ([http://www.bakefile.org][1])
#     Do not modify, all changes will be overwritten!
# =========================================================================
```

4. I ran `make` in `build-gtk/samples`, which compiled all examples except `build-gtk/samples/mediaplayer` and `build-gtk/samples/splash`.

Following @VZ.'s answer I also tried to manually compile `build-gtk/samples/mediaplayer` using `g++` and changing the **order** of the *libraries* I got the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstvideo-1.0.so: undefined reference to `gst_event_parse_instant_rate_change'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstvideo-1.0.so: undefined reference to `gst_aggregator_simple_get_next_time'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstvideo-1.0.so: undefined reference to `gst_base_sink_set_processing_deadline'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstvideo-1.0.so: undefined reference to `gst_mini_object_add_parent'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstvideo-1.0.so: undefined reference to `gst_mini_object_remove_parent'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstvideo-1.0.so: undefined reference to `gst_aggregator_selected_samples'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

**Edit 2:**
I fixed the aforementioned error by running the following:

```
sudo rm /usr/local/lib/libgstbase-1.0.so*
sudo rm /usr/local/lib/libgstreamer-1.0.*
```

effectively removing any `gstreamer` libraries under `/usr/local/lib` that seemed to be conflicting with some other `gstreamer` libraries elsewhere in the system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem with the order of the libraries in the link command you show, gstreamer libraries must come *after* `-lwx_gtk3u-3.1` and not before it as they do, when using static libraries.

<strike>It's not clear to me where does this command actually come from, normally you should run `make` inside `build-gtk/samples/mediaplayer` directory, is this really what you're doing? I.e. how exactly do you the provided makefiles and which ones are you using?</strike>

This looks like a bug in static monolithic build when using media library and should be fixed in wxWidgets itself. I don't know about the new errors, i.e. the missing `gst_event_parse_instant_rate_change` and other symbols, I don't have anything like this on my system, so I suspect this might be due to a mix of gstreamer libraries on your system due to your previous attempts to circumvent the problem.

P.S. Avoid using all these `--enable-xxx` options, they're all on by default anyhow (and those that are off are usually off for a good reason).

Comment: Thank you for answer and for the tip. The instruction was to run `make` inside `build-gtk/samples`, which had a `makefile`, and it would automatically run `make` inside each example (I think the make files inside each example e.g. *mediaplayer* were created by something called a `bakefile` which I have no idea what it is. All the other examples compiled fine. Now trying to compile it manually, I changed the order of the libraries but I get the following error (next comment): Edit: I'll edit the original post after all